# Manage null with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

With this code

```
 var res = (from p in list where 
           p.FirstName.ToUpper() == firstName.ToUpper() || 
           p.LastName.ToUpper() == lastName.ToUpper() select p).ToList<Client>();
```

The p.FirstName, or the firstName can be NULL how can I manage this ?

Thanks,

Comment: This seems like a very strange query. If firstname and lastname are "John" and "Smith" then the client list is everyone whose first name is John, and everyone whose last name is Smith. Are you sure this query is the one you actually want?

Comment: the firstname is not mandatory

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
where String.Equals(p.LastName, lastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer (as of right now) that uses `string.Equals`.

Comment: Although `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` matches the OP's request, I suspect `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` would be more appropriate for this application. But anything is better than `ToUpper`.

Answer (score 4):

Use String.Equals() specifying case insensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `string.Compare` when dealing with non-case-sensitive strings, like:

```
bool areEquivalent = string.Compare(s1, s2, true) == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = (from p in list where 
       p.FirstName != null && firstName != null && p.FirstName.ToUpper() == firstName.ToUpper() || 
       p.LastName.ToUpper() == lastName.ToUpper() select p).ToList<Client>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var res = (from p in list where 
    (p.FirstName ?? "").ToUpper() == (firstName ?? "").ToUpper() || 
    (p.LastName ?? "").ToUpper() == (lastName ?? "").ToUpper() select p)
    .ToList<Client>();
```

It really depends on what you want to do when either is `null`. This should treat `null` as equivalent to an empty string for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Compare` for this.

```
string x = null;
string y = null;

//both NUnit tests pass
Assert.IsTrue(string.Equals(x, y));
Assert.AreEqual(0, string.Compare(x, y, true));

...

var ignoreCase = true;
var res = (from p in list 
           where string.Compare(p.FirstName, firstName, ignoreCase) == 0 || 
                 string.Compare(p.LastName, lastName, ignoreCase) == 0 
           select p).ToList<Client>();
```